# Azure/Powershell: How to list application configuration

Tags: azure, powershell

What command can be run in Powershell to display all of the configuration parameters for a given application, e.g., "ReplyUrls", "HomePage", etc.?

Comment: Do you mean external applications (executables)? What do you mean by configuration parameters? Or do you mean command-line parameters? Please update your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly install the azure powershell module:

```
Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser
```

Connect to your azure account with the following command (This will request the username and password of your azure account):

```
Connect-AzAccount
```

Then use the following command to get the ReplyURLs / Homepage etc of your applications:

```
Get-AzADApplication
```